# How skip special chachter from solr term vector

Tags: solr, lucene

When I use solr term vector for a document, it's remove special character and split word from each special character like below:

```
info@gmail.com -> info gmail.com
http://www.google.com - > http www.google.com
```

How can fix it?

Comment: can you share the schema.xml used?

Comment: Term vectors are for iterating over the indexed (post-analysis) terms.  If you want the whole stored contents of the field, you should access that via the stored field.

Comment: Are you using wordDelimiterFilter?

Comment: @Oyeme no , how can use it ?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters